# В DRF при серилизации вместо foreignkey возвращать связанное имя. И не в кортеже

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Пример:

models.py:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    serviceName = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.serviceName

class Office(models.Model):
    officeName = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.officeName 


class SendNotification(models.Model):
    office = models.ForeignKey(Office, related_name='notify', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, related_name='notify', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    notificationName = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    eventdatetime = models.DateTimeField()
    success = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.notificationName
```

serializers.py:

```
class OfficeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Office
        fields = ['officeName']

class ServiceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ['serviceName']


class SendNotificationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    office= OfficeSerializer(read_only=True)
    service = ServiceSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = BackupNotification
        fields = ['office', 'service', 'notificationName ', 'eventdatetime', 'success']
```

При get по /v1/api/notify/
Я получаю такую картину:

```
{
    "notify": [
        {
            "office": {
                "officeName": "Тестовый"
            },
            "service": {
                "serviceName": "Тестовая"
            },
            "backupName": "Тестовый сообщение",
            "eventdatetime": "2020-01-15T20:00:09Z",
            "success": true
        }
}
```

Вопрос в том, можно ли возвращать вместо массива в значении service или office обычный текст?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
class SendNotificationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    office= serializers.CharField(source='office.officeName')
    service = serializers.CharField(source='service.serviceName')
    class Meta:
        model = BackupNotification
        fields = ['office', 'service', 'notificationName ', 'eventdatetime', 'success']
```